# dynamic table data is not getting rendered in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a table on expanding the icon

```
expandable={{
            expandedRowRender: () => {
              return (
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                  {props.data.map(obj => {
                    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        return (
                          <tr>
                            <td>{key}</td>
                            <td>{value}</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                    })
                  })}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              )
            },
```

but this isnt rendering anything, The table data is dynamic keys and values from the object.  can someone tell me what im doing wrong here?